# Scroll horizonte no componente nav-tabs (bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Eu adicionei um `scroll` horizontal no componente `nav-tabs` do bootstrap 4.

Agora quero que o `scroll` funcione de forma automática caso eu clique no ultimo `tab visível`, e mostre o próximo `tab` que está fora do display.

[Este link mostra examente o que pretendo fazer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjtrxy)

É possivel fazer isto com javascript ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="Juan Diego Torres Castillo">
      <title>Bootstrap Init Template</title>
      <!-- Boostrap CSS & Icons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>
         .nav-tabs {
         z-index: 1;
         position: relative;
         /* scroll */
         overflow-x: auto !important;
         overflow-y:hidden !important; 
         flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
         }
      </style>
      <h1>Template Boostrap</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab1" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab2" class="nav-link  active" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab3" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab4" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab5" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab6" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab7" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 7</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab8" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 8</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab9" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 9</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab10" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 10</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab11" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 11</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab12" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 12</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab13" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 13</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 1</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane show active">
            <h1>This is tab 2</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 3</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 4</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab5" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 5</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab6" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 6</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab7" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 7</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab8" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 8</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab9" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 9</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab10" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 10</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab11" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 11</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab12" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 12</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab13" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 13</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `.animate()` do jQuery, mas é preciso usar a versão full da biblioteca. No seu código está usando a versão slim, que não possui o `.animate()`. É só substituir a biblioteca:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Por:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Veja como fica (explicações de funcionamento comentado no código):

```js
$(".nav-tabs li").on("click", function(){ // pega os clicks nas tabs
   var ante = $(this).prev(); // pego a tab antes da que foi clicada
   var prox = $(this).next(); // pego a tab após a que foi clicada
   if(~prox.index()){ // verifica se existe
      var distLeft = Math.ceil(prox.offset().left); // distância da esquerda
      var proxWidth = Math.ceil(prox.width()); // pega a largura da tab
      if(distLeft+proxWidth >= window.innerWidth){ // verifica se está fora da tela (inteiramente ou parcialmente)
         $(this).parent().animate({ // faz o scroll animado para aparecer a tab
            // soma a distância, a largura e o que já foi rolado e subtrai pela largura da janela
            scrollLeft: distLeft+proxWidth+$(this).parent().scrollLeft() - window.innerWidth
         }, 200); // tempo de 200ms: 1/5 de segundo de animação
         return; // abandona a função
      }
   }
   
   if(~ante.index()){ // verifica se existe uma tab anterior
      var distLeft = Math.ceil(ante.offset().left); // distância da esquerda
      if(distLeft < 0){ // verifica se está fora da tela (inteiramente ou parcialmente)
         $(this).parent().animate({ // faz o scroll animado para aparecer a tab
            // soma o que já foi rolado com a distância da esquerda da janela
            scrollLeft: $(this).parent().scrollLeft()+distLeft
         }, 200); // tempo de 200ms: 1/5 de segundo de animação
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="Juan Diego Torres Castillo">
      <title>Bootstrap Init Template</title>
      <!-- Boostrap CSS & Icons -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <style>
         .nav-tabs {
         z-index: 1;
         position: relative;
         /* scroll */
         overflow-x: auto !important;
         overflow-y:hidden !important; 
         flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
         }
      </style>
      <h1>Template Boostrap</h1>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab1" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab2" class="nav-link  active" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab3" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab4" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab5" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab6" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 6</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab7" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 7</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab8" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 8</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab9" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 9</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab10" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 10</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab11" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 11</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab12" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 12</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#tab13" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Tab 13</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 1</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane show active">
            <h1>This is tab 2</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 3</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 4</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab5" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 5</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab6" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 6</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab7" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 7</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab8" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 8</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab9" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 9</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab10" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 10</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab11" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 11</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab12" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 12</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="tab13" class="tab-pane">
            <h1>This is tab 13</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigado pela resposta, como este mesmo código, posso fazer um If else para verificar quando for o primeiro tab e não o último?

Comment: Resposta alterada com a função de voltar também.

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!!